# React native facebook iOS sdk build failed

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I've follow all the guidelines listed on Facebook developer guide for the iOS react native sdk but i'm still unable to build the app. Attached a screenshot of my config and the build log

[image]

> Ld /Users/alaaattya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alnomad-fcoerljazsnnxbggcygydgyxmimr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alnomad.app/Alnomad normal x86_64
>       cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/marscodes/alnomad-ios/ios
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -L/Users/alaaattya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alnomad-fcoerljazsnnxbggcygydgyxmimr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/alaaattya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alnomad-fcoerljazsnnxbggcygydgyxmimr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/marscodes/alnomad-ios/ios/../node_modules/react-native-facebook-login/FacebookSDK -F/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/marscodes/alnomad-ios/ios -F. -FAlnomad -FAlnomadTests -Fbuild -FFacebookSDK -Fbuild/Build -Fbuild/Logs -FFacebookSDK/AccountKitStrings.bundle -FFacebookSDK/DocSets -FFacebookSDK/FacebookSDKStrings.bundle -FFacebookSDK/Samples -Fbuild/Logs/Build -FFacebookSDK/AccountKitStrings.bundle/Resources -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookAudienceNetworkSDK-4_13-for-iOS.docset -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookMessengerShareKitSDK-1_3-for-iOS.docset -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookSDK-4_13-for-iOS.docset -FFacebookSDK/FacebookSDKStrings.bundle/Resources -FFacebookSDK/Samples/Configurations -FFacebookSDK/Samples/FBAudienceNetwork -FFacebookSDK/Samples/Iconicus -FFacebookSDK/Samples/RPSSample -FFacebookSDK/Samples/Scrumptious -FFacebookSDK/Samples/ShareIt -FFacebookSDK/Samples/SwitchUserSample -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookAudienceNetworkSDK-4_13-for-iOS.docset/Contents -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookMessengerShareKitSDK-1_3-for-iOS.docset/Contents -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookSDK-4_13-for-iOS.docset/Contents -FFacebookSDK/Samples/FBAudienceNetwork/AdUnitsSample -FFacebookSDK/Samples/FBAudienceNetwork/NativeAdSample -FFacebookSDK/Samples/Iconicus/Configurations -FFacebookSDK/Samples/Iconicus/Iconicus -FFacebookSDK/Samples/RPSSample/RPSSample -FFacebookSDK/Samples/Scrumptious/scrumptious -FFacebookSDK/Samples/ShareIt/ShareIt -FFacebookSDK/Samples/SwitchUserSample/SwitchUserSample -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookAudienceNetworkSDK-4_13-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookMessengerShareKitSDK-1_3-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookSDK-4_13-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources -FFacebookSDK/Samples/FBAudienceNetwork/AdUnitsSample/AdUnitsSample -FFacebookSDK/Samples/FBAudienceNetwork/NativeAdSample/NativeAdSample -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookAudienceNetworkSDK-4_13-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookMessengerShareKitSDK-1_3-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookSDK-4_13-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookAudienceNetworkSDK-4_13-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/Classes -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookAudienceNetworkSDK-4_13-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/Constants -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookAudienceNetworkSDK-4_13-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/css -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookAudienceNetworkSDK-4_13-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/img -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookAudienceNetworkSDK-4_13-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/Protocols -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookMessengerShareKitSDK-1_3-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/Classes -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookMessengerShareKitSDK-1_3-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/Constants -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookMessengerShareKitSDK-1_3-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/css -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookMessengerShareKitSDK-1_3-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/img -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookMessengerShareKitSDK-1_3-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/Protocols -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookSDK-4_13-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/Classes -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookSDK-4_13-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/Constants -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookSDK-4_13-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/css -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookSDK-4_13-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/img -FFacebookSDK/DocSets/FacebookSDK-4_13-for-iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/Protocols -F/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/marscodes/alnomad-ios/ios/FacebookSDK -filelist /Users/alaaattya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alnomad-fcoerljazsnnxbggcygydgyxmimr/Build/Intermediates/Alnomad.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alnomad.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Alnomad.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime /Users/alaaattya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alnomad-fcoerljazsnnxbggcygydgyxmimr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a /Users/alaaattya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alnomad-fcoerljazsnnxbggcygydgyxmimr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTActionSheet.a -framework FBSDKLoginKit /Users/alaaattya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alnomad-fcoerljazsnnxbggcygydgyxmimr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTGeolocation.a /Users/alaaattya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alnomad-fcoerljazsnnxbggcygydgyxmimr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTImage.a /Users/alaaattya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alnomad-fcoerljazsnnxbggcygydgyxmimr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTLinking.a /Users/alaaattya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alnomad-fcoerljazsnnxbggcygydgyxmimr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTNetwork.a /Users/alaaattya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alnomad-fcoerljazsnnxbggcygydgyxmimr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTSettings.a -framework FBSDKShareKit /Users/alaaattya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alnomad-fcoerljazsnnxbggcygydgyxmimr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTText.a /Users/alaaattya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alnomad-fcoerljazsnnxbggcygydgyxmimr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTVibration.a /Users/alaaattya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alnomad-fcoerljazsnnxbggcygydgyxmimr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTWebSocket.a -lRNVectorIcons -framework FBSDKCoreKit -lRNI18n -lRCTFBSDK -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/alaaattya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alnomad-fcoerljazsnnxbggcygydgyxmimr/Build/Intermediates/Alnomad.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alnomad.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Alnomad_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/alaaattya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alnomad-fcoerljazsnnxbggcygydgyxmimr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alnomad.app/Alnomad
>
> ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied 'FacebookSDK/Bolts.framework/Bolts', framework linker option at FacebookSDK/Bolts.framework/Bolts is not a dylib
>   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKHashtag", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libRCTFBSDK.a(RCTConvert+FBSDKSharingContent.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 6):

I am recently doing the same thing on my react native project and I have spent quite some time to make it work too.

Your case seems to be that you did not include `Bolts.framework`, a dependency of the `FBSDKCoreKit.framework`, in your project folder. I believe that's the reason why the Facebook official doc recommends everyone to keep the SDK files in `~/Documents`, so you don't miss dependency files, or having to duplicate these files on each of your project.

Below are some troubleshooting steps for anyone who is having issues with the integration:

**1. Link `react-native-fbsdk` to your project. (Edit: As of lately, linking doesn't work with the SDK. According to @chez.mosey's answer below, you may follow steps in this [blog](http://www.namvo.me/manual-setup-for-facebook-sdk-in-react-native/) to manually add the SDK to your project.)**

`rnpm link react-native-fbsdk`

```
react-native link react-native-fbsdk
```

Edit: `rnpm` has been integrated into React Native since 1 Aug, 2016. From then on, use `react-native link` to link your dependencies.

The `link` function updates your project by linking all native dependencies, and in this case, we link `react-native-fbsdk` to the native FacebookSDK.

**2. Add `libRCTFBSDK.a` to Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries in Xcode.**

This should be automatically added when you run `react-native link`, but make sure it's there.

**3. Import FacebookSDK framework files manually**

Speaking from experience, if you are using Cocoapods to download the FBSDK framework files, Xcode won't build them along with `libRCTFBSDK.a`. Follow the steps in the official FB doc, download the files, unzip them to `~/Documents/FacebookSDK`, and drag them to your Xcode project without copying them. Add the path to your framework search path.
(If anyone knows the reason why Cocoapods won't work, I'm all ears)

**4. Clean your Xcode project and delete derived data**

Do that to avoid having the previously built files messing with your current settings.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer, but it still seems to not work... everything builds up until I include `libRCTFBSDK.a`...

Comment: Not too sure where you find `libRCTFBSDK.a`. It's not included in the Facebook SDK downloaded from Facebook

Comment: @jacks205 the library file will be included in your Xcode project once you've done linking with `react-native-fbsdk`

Comment: @tropicalfish right now linking is not working. Can you or someone else tell me how to add this file manually?

Comment: Has anyone resolved this? I have follow the setup steps exactly, but libRCTFBSDK.a is no where to be found.

Answer (score 2):

When you download FacebookSDK from (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/) the folder will be named as FacebookSDKs-iOS-4.20.1.
So, try renaming it to FacebookSDK.

**Then clean and build your Xcode project again.**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to download and keep the FacebookSDK folder on your computer (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/). I usually place it in ~/Documents/FacebookSDK and reference it from the build settings. This is in addition to dragging over the 3 framework files into the Frameworks folder.

Comment: as it's in the screenshot i've did dragged the 3 .framework files and also put the sdk folder in the right path there

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, make sure your follow all of the configuration steps for the SDK here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/configure-ios/

After doing this, I encountered the issue mentioned in the Troubleshooting section, "If you get a build error like 'Warning: Native component for 'RCTFBLikeView' does not exist,' verify that libRCTFBSDK.a shows up in the Link Binary with Libraries section of your build target's Build Phases." Which I believe is the issue you are encountering.

The problem is, I didn't know how to resolve the fact that libRCTFBSDK.a wasn't showing up. Turns out, it was because react-native-fbsdk wasn't linking properly, and thus I had to link it manually, which I was able to do following the wonderful steps provided here: http://www.namvo.me/manual-setup-for-facebook-sdk-in-react-native/