# react-native .38 Facebook login on iOS show a red rectangle instead of Login Button

Tags: ios, react-native, facebook-login, react-native-fbsdk

I am trying to implement FaceBook login using react-native. Followed the exact steps from:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

App builds fine, but it doesn't display the FBLogin button. it shows a red rectangle instead.

I saw some similar issues discussed on android, but don't see a clear answer yet. Have anyone faced this ? Any suggestions or pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by copying the fbsdk to the app itself and linking the libraries from there, instead of keeping it in ~/Documents as the documentation suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The Red rectangle appears when the react-native-fbsdk is not linked to the Xcode project.

use this command 
    rnpm link react-native-fbsdk

You can find how to do the linking here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41217581